# How can I maake MBOX files (Unix-style email archives) searchable via Spotlight in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, email, spotlight, mbox

I have a tons of Unix-style mbox e-mail files accumulated for more
than ten years, used with MH and other Unix-based mail readers.

Is there any way to let MacOS Spotlight to recognize
these Unix-style mail files (their filenames just consist of numbers,
without filename extension, and its contents are MIME encoded)?

I want these mail files searchable with 'mdfind' command and
metadata such as "kMDItemAuthorEmailAddresses", without modifying
their file names.

Thanks!

Comment: I exported a few years worth of Outlook 2011 emails to MBOX thinking spotlight would automatically work with them, but apparently that is not true under Yosemite 10.10, so I am interested in a fix for this as well

Answer (score 1):

[This old mac tip](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080204084457302) still works:

Find the .mbox files created by Apple Mail (under ~/Library/Mail/V4 in OSX 10.12.6.)  Each account gets a directory named with a long hash, and the mboxes are in those directories.  If you copy one of those, say, to the desktop, then all of the messages will immediately show up in spotlight.  If you open or double-click the message from the spotlight search, it will open right up in mail and you can reply as though you never archived the folder.

[edit] By the way, I think there are two kinds of mbox files around.  The kind you want have each message as an individual file in a folder structure, whereas sometimes I think they come as just a single large file and an index.  If you have the latter kind, maybe you can use Apple mail to create the former kind — by importing into a folder — and then using the above tip.  If you've got the right kind, though, just copying it out of ~/Library as above should make spotlight aware of the contents.